# Python: Nested while loop inside a for loop breaking unexpectedly without any error

Tags: python, loops, python-requests, google-cloud-firestore

I have a while loop nested within a for loop that's running over a json array collected from firestore, which collects stock symbols to pass to another api to gather minute by minute trading data to put back into the firestore db.

While I'm running the loop, it'll stop unexpectedly without any error around the fourth or sixth (never more) time through the 389 entry while loop.

Any idea why this is? Is it something with my code? I noticed if I changed the limit in the while loop from 389 down to 100, it worked through all the companies within the json array. But it won't get through many than four companies down the list if it's the full 389 entries.

Anyway, thanks for the help!

```
import requests
import json
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
import datetime

cred = credentials.Certificate("./serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

doc_ref1 = db.collection(u'Quiver').stream()

for doc in doc_ref1:

    symbol = doc.id

    api_url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/{}/chart/1d".format(symbol)

    query_url = api_url

    r = requests.get(query_url)

    if r.status_code != 200: 
        print("Error:", r.status_code)
        continue

    if r.status_code == 404: 
        print("Error:", r.status_code, symbol)
        continue

    json_stock = r.json()

    b = 0

    while b <= 100:
        try:
            date = json_stock[b]['date']

            minute = json_stock[b]['minute']

            label = json_stock[b]['label']

            high = json_stock[b]['high']

            low = json_stock[b]['low']

            average = json_stock[b]['average']

            volume = json_stock[b]['volume']

            notional = json_stock[b]['notional']

            numberOfTrades = json_stock[b]['numberOfTrades']

            marketHigh = json_stock[b]['marketHigh']

            marketLow = json_stock[b]['marketLow']

            marketAverage = json_stock[b]['marketAverage']

            marketVolume = json_stock[b]['marketVolume']

            marketNotional = json_stock[b]['marketNotional']

            marketNumberOfTrades = json_stock[b]['marketNumberOfTrades']

            open = json_stock[b]['open']

            close = json_stock[b]['close']

            marketOpen = json_stock[b]['marketOpen']

            marketClose = json_stock[b]['marketClose']

            changeOverTime = json_stock[b]['changeOverTime']

            marketChangeOverTime = json_stock[b]['marketChangeOverTime']

            doc_ref = db.collection(u'dailies').document(u'{}-{}'.format(minute, symbol))

            doc_ref.set({
                u'date':u'{}'.format(date),
                u'minute':u'{}'.format(minute),
                u'label':u'{}'.format(label),
                u'high':u'{}'.format(high),
                u'average':u'{}'.format(average),
                u'notional':u'{}'.format(notional),
                u'number of trades':u'{}'.format(numberOfTrades),
                u'market high':u'{}'.format(marketHigh),
                u'market low':u'{}'.format(marketLow),
                u'market average':u'{}'.format(marketAverage),
                u'market volume':u'{}'.format(marketVolume),
                u'market notional':u'{}'.format(marketNotional),
                u'market number of trades':u'{}'.format(marketNumberOfTrades),
                u'open':u'{}'.format(open),
                u'close':u'{}'.format(close),
                u'market open':u'{}'.format(marketOpen),
                u'market close':u'{}'.format(marketClose),
                u'change over time':u'{}'.format(changeOverTime),
                u'market change over time':u'{}'.format(marketChangeOverTime)
            })

            print("{} {}:  {}".format(symbol, minute, b))

            b += 1

        except IndexError:
            print("Index Error")
            break
```

Comment: What do you mean without any error? Your IndexError exception breaks, so that wouldn't throw, but there should still be something printed. Or in the other direction, is there some other kind of exception occurring that you aren't catching?

Comment: You're probably erroring out with a KeyError exception somewhere. If you're not 100% sure that the data you're acquiring has every single field, you should change your ["key"] format to .get("key")

Comment: So I restarted my machine and ran it again. Now it's throwing up an Index Error over and over. Is there something I need to alter so it runs through the whole list?

Comment: Are you still getting at least 100 results?

Comment: Ya, it's still running through the first few companies and iterating through their data. For each symbol, there's 389 commits of data, and it's running through the first 5 symbols before giving me the index error.

Comment: 389 commits of data doesn't mean 389 commits of data are being returned. From the code you posted, there's only one "index," so there's really only one place that could be throwing that error. add some checks to json_stock

Comment: Oh ok. What checks should I be adding in?

Comment: `print(len(json_stock))` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
except Exception as errmsg:
        print(errmsg)
```

and provide more information